# how can I return as a string with everything in the array per row?

Tags: java, arrays, return

Hello I am trying to figure out after looking through a double array:

```
public static String  returnWhatIsInTheArrayAsAString(char [][] a){
    String whatIs = " ";
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){

        }
    }
    return whatIs + "\n";
}
```

How do I return what was in both arrays, if that makes sense? How do I add that to my \n?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase it? Or post a small example of input/output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the characters to the String as they appear while you loop through them:

```
public class Test {
        public static String  returnWhatIsInTheArrayAsAString(char [][] a){
            String whatIs = " ";
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
                   whatIs += a[i][j];
                }
                whatIs += "\n";
            }
            return whatIs + "\n";
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            char[][] foo = new char[][] {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}, {'g', 'h', 'i'}};
            System.out.println(returnWhatIsInTheArrayAsAString(foo));
        }
    }
```

Comment: So this seems to be the right way, I just need every word to be on a new line. 
 
and it compiles like this : fspnsryshburaqpyypjiyyqgknsylv

Comment: I think I've modified the answer to do that. Is this what you mean - adding a \n after each iteration of the first loop through the 2D array?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you have char[][] which you are treating essentially like an array of strings and you want to return one string with each member of the array separated by a new line character? Then it is relatively simple.

```
public static String  returnWhatIsInTheArrayAsAString(char [][] a){
        StringBuilder whatIs = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
           whatIs.append(new String(a[i])).append('\n');
        }
        return whatIs.toString();
    }
}
```

If what you want is to return the contents of the array as one string then maybe something like:

```
public static String returnWhatIsInTheArrayAsAString(char[][] a) {
    StringBuilder whatIs = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        whatIs.append('{ ');
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            whatIs.append(a[i][j]);

            if(j < a[i].length - 1){
              whatIs.append(', ');
            }
        }
        whatIs.append(' }\n');
    }
    return whatIs.toString();
}
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` and `new String(char[] value)` for row.

```
public static String returnWhatIsInTheArrayAsAString(char[][] array) {
    String string = "";
    for (char[] row : array) {
        string += new String(row) + "\n";
    }
    return string;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    char[][] foo = new char[][] {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}, {'g', 'h', 'i'}};
    System.out.println(returnWhatIsInTheArrayAsAString(foo));
}
```

will return

```
abc
def
ghi
```